# using zclip to copy multiple values with multiple copy buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

I would like to be able copy the value of class attribute, using it's accompanied copy button.

For lack of better phrasing, here's an example:

[image]

Currently the copy button only works for one copy button (whichever is first).

How do copy from multiple element, using multiple buttons?

code:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.copylink').zclip({
         path: '/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
           copy: function(){ return $(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl'); },
           afterCopy: function()
           {
               console.log($(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl') + " was copied to clipboard");
           }
        });
  });
```

all buttons have the same classes etc:

```
<button class="copyshortened copylink" data-copy-shorturl="http://litl.it/{{$link->short_url}}">copy</button>
```

I'm not sure why `$(this)` in jquery, doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: make sure you are using at least the 1.1.0 version, until which **`$(this)` selector was not supported in callback functions** ([as shown in their bugs section](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#bugs))

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thank you for the reply, I'm currently using 1.1.1 version.  It only seems to initialize on the first button.

Comment: If you post a Fiddle I will try to fix it for you.

Comment: @GuyT I've created a fiddle that works just fine, http://jsfiddle.net/rK974/.  I think there maybe a conflict with the sorting plugin that I'm using, mixitup by kunkalabs.  But there is no errors or no seemingly obvious conflict, and that is where I am right now.  Which is kinda' unfortunate.

Comment: @samayres1992 I'm not able to open your Fiddle, but I guess you forgot the `.each`(jQuery, `for` in pure JS). See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/27cucr6n/ . I can't open your Fiddle, but that's probably a site problem because I also can't open others(404).

Comment: This fits to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/27cucr6n/1/

Comment: @GuyT, hi there, I just checked out the fiddle, and unfortunately the buttons do not work.

Comment: @samayres1992 Did you check your console? I've checked it and can confirm it works in FF, Chrome and IE.

Comment: @samayres1992 Be aware that my first Fiddle(27cucr6n) needs some text in the inputboxes before they show something in the console.

Comment: Hi @GuyT, did you manage to see my current fiddle? It seems fine but the issue seems to be when used with the mixitup plugin.  As the copy buttons work just fine on the fiddle I have shared.

Comment: @samayres1992 I'm sorry but I still cannot open your Fiddle(404). What your problem could be is a `jQuery` conflict. A possible solutions is to set `var j = $.noConflict();` and replace every `$` with `j`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @samayres1992 Could you share the solution with us? You have accepted an answer that was provided on 4th of August, but it still was not solved on the 7th of August(check above comment).

Comment: @GuyT The bounty was up as of yesterday, and the answer below was the correct code to apply zClip to each button.  I felt it was unfair to not award the person the bounty because the reason why it's not working for me right now is due to a javascript conflicting issue.

Comment: @GuyT I'm a little disappointed that I still can't get it to work, I've given the noconflict jquery a try but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @samayres1992 Now I can open your Fiddle :) . I've edited the zclip js file. Now you are able to use `$.noConflict`. Could you try it with my edited code: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/rK974/1/ ? *see new zclip version in external resources*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do, but I think your syntax is a little off.

You are applying ***zclip*** like an event rather than as a directive.

Try this

```
$('.copylink').each(function(){
    $(this).zclip({
        path :  '/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
           copy: function(){ return $(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl'); },
           afterCopy: function()
           {
               console.log($(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl') + " was copied to clipboard");
           }
    });
});
```

---

### Update

```
$('.copylink').each(function(){
    $(this).zclip({
        path :  '/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
           copy: function(){ return $(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl'); },
           afterCopy: function()
           {
               console.log($(this).data('copy-shorturl') + " was copied to clipboard");
           }
    });
});
```

Apparently, the `data-copy-shorturl` attributes should be accessed via jQuery's [data function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've given this a try inside and outside of a document.ready.  With solely the each function, it fails too initialize on any button, within a doc ready function, it works for the first button.  Maybe it's an issue with the positioning of the script in the document? I currently just have it in the <head> tag.  Here is the console return for the button, it seems to return all the values fine, http://cl.ly/image/2q1f2u0x1b3q/Image%202014-08-04%20at%206.59.45%20AM.png Thoughts?

Comment: You should use Ready event, nothing else should matter... esp script positioning...

Comment: I just gave this a try, and it gave the same result.  Although I did use the console and checked out the the values of 'this' using breakpoints.  And it does initialize on each of the buttons, but when it comes to the page fully loaded, the flash object isn't applied to the buttons (apart from the first one).  Here is a screencap: http://cl.ly/image/3e0d3j1F3e1p/Image%202014-08-05%20at%206.24.57%20AM.png Any further thoughts why this isn't working? Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: I've just been playing around with it further, the fiddle works fine.  I guess there must be some sort of conflict. http://jsfiddle.net/rK974/

Comment: @samayres1992, Good job with the Fiddle. For now I'm at a loss. I will try some more research. LMK if you come up with more angles...

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is an issue with maybe the values being produced via php, whereas in the fiddle, it's static html.  And thank you for looking in to it, I'm really stumped at where it's gone wrong.

Comment: @samayres1992, are you using a framework in php... could it be adding attributes and or JS/JQ layers? A JS file you are including? I'm trying to reduce what may be different... cause it's not the php alone. It has to be the HTML DOC that results. If that's no different...

Comment: I'm currently using laravel framework, as far as I'm aware that shouldn't be an issue.  I think maybe it would be more likely that the sorting jquery plugin I'm using could be the reason.  I'm using mixitup by kunkalabs, and I know it definitely changes the dom onload, but the html within them for the buttons are the still the same.

Comment: @samayres1992, try removing libraries until it works. Or maybe even remove all js libraries and see if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work perfectly for me. Please check [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitsnghn/b3Lkq128/). Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

**HTML :**

```
<button class="copyshortened copylink" data-copy-shorturl="http://google.com">copy google link</button>
<button class="copyshortened copylink" data-copy-shorturl="http://yahoo.com">copy yahoo link</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
window.onload = loaded();
function loaded()
{
    $('.copylink').zclip({
        path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function(){ return $(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl'); },
        afterCopy: function()
        {
            console.log($(this).attr('data-copy-shorturl') + " was copied to clipboard");
        }
    });
}
```